# how to disable chrome application context menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I can not figure out how to hide the context menu on my chrome app for the love of god
i'v tried this

```js
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

but it only works in the browser not in the apps html file i tried

```js
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
```

also wont work what do i do

Comment: can anyone help me

Comment: Does [anything here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus) help?

Comment: yes post it as an answer and il make you it

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use a simple link as an answer, as it would be considered a low quality answer. (and links tend to change over time) No big deal for me, though, glad it helped.

Comment: "in the apps html file" - if you really meant a [chrome app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps), they can't run any code in html by default so you should use a separate js file loaded using a standard `<script src="file.js"></script>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it on the body of the document like this...

```
document.body.addEventListener('contextmenu',function(e){ SomeFunc(); },false);
```

Comment: @ArticScript - why accept an answer that didn't work?

Comment: becuse their's no answers valid besides Paul T which wasn't an answer

Comment: @ArticScript ... you don't have to accept any answer that doesn't match. You can, however, answer your own question (and accept it later too) if you can make an answer (a little detail/info and relative code) a to share what you discovered that may help others.

Answer (score -1):

If this is in an iframe don't forget the correct format to access the window...

```
YourID.contentWindow.document.body.addEventListener(); //etc
```